# add 2hr in datetime field in mule 3

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mulesoft, mule-esb

I'm trying to add two hours in datetime but always getting this error."Cannot coerce a :string to a :datetime, caused by :Text '2021-04-05 21:29:55' could not be parsed at index 2"

Please give solution.

dataweave code:

```
            %dw 1.0
            %output application/json
            ---
            {
                dateA: "2021-04-05 21:29:55" as :datetime {format: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"} + |PT2H|
            }
```

expected output:

```
            {
                dateA: "2021-04-05 23:29:55"
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
            %dw 1.0
            %output application/json
            ---
            {
            dateA: (("2021-04-05 21:29:55" as :localdatetime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}) + |PT2H|) as :localdatetime {format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"}
            }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).